# NoReverseMatch for user profile view

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls, django-2.2

I need two different views for the user:

- a view *user_details*, it show the details of model *User*;
- a view *user_profile*, it show the details of model *UserProfile*

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='profile_user',
    )
    many_other_fields....
```

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, HttpResponseRedirect, redirect, render

from .models import UserProfile

def user_details(request, username):
    user_details = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
    template = 'usermanager/reading/user_details.html'
    context = {
        'user': user_details,
    }
    return render(request, template, context)

def user_profile(request, username):
    profile = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, username=profile_user.username)
    template = 'usermanager/reading/user_profile.html'
    context = {
        'user_profile': profile,
    }
    return render(request, template, context)
```

**urls.py**

```
path('account-manager/<username>/', views.user_details, name="user_details"),
path('account-manager/<username>/profile/', views.user_profile, name="user_profile"),
```

**template.html**

```
<a href="{% url 'user_details' username=user.username %}">User Details</a>
<a href="{% url 'user_profile' username=userprofile.profile_user.username %}">User Profile</a>
```

With this approach I see the error below:

> NoReverseMatch at /account-manager/max/ Reverse for 'user_profile'
>   with keyword arguments '{'username': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s)
>   tried: ['account\-manager\/(?P[^/]+)\/profile\/$']

How I can solve this problem? Can you suggest me another approach?

**FULL TRACEBACK**

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/account-manager/

Django Version: 2.2.5
Python Version: 3.6.8
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'kernel',
 'usermanager']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template /home/max/Django/area-test/app_usermanager_dev/app_usermanager/usermanager/templates/usermanager/backend_nav.html, error at line 11
   Reverse for 'user_profile' with keyword arguments '{'username': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['account\\-manager\\/(?P<username>[^/]+)\\/profile\\/$']
   1 : {% load static %}
   2 : <div class="px-2 pt-2 navbar sticky-top">
   3 : 
   4 :   <div class="" id="nav_container">
   5 : 
   6 :     <nav class="navbar flex-column navbar-dark" id="nav_single">
   7 :         <p class="nav-item"><a id="nav_link" href="/"><i class="fas fa-home"></i> Site Home</a></p>
   8 :         <hr>
   9 :         <p class="nav-item"><a id="nav_link" href="{% url 'dashboard' %}"><i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i> Dashboard</a></p>
   10 :         <p class="nav-item"><a id="nav_link" href="{% url 'user_details' username=user.username %}"><i class="fas fa-user-circle"></i> User Details</a></p>
   11 :         <p class="nav-item"><a id="nav_link" href=" {% url 'user_profile' username=userprofile.user.username %} "><i class="fas fas fa-id-card"></i> User Profile</a></p>
   12 :         <p class="nav-item"><a id="nav_link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-clipboard-list"></i> Buyed Products</a></p>
   13 :     </nav>
   14 : 
   15 : 
   16 : 
   17 :     <hr>
   18 :     <nav id="nav_single">
   19 :       <p class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" href="{% url 'logout' %}"><i class="fas fa-power-off"></i></a></p>
   20 :     </nav>
   21 : 


Traceback:

File "/home/max/Django/area-test/app_usermanager_dev/devenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/max/Django/area-test/app_usermanager_dev/devenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/max/Django/area-test/app_usermanager_dev/devenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/home/max/Django/area-test/app_usermanager_dev/app_usermanager/usermanager/views.py" in dashboard
  100.     return render(request, template)

File "/home/max/Django/area-test/app_usermanager_dev/devenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render
  36.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

File "/home/max/Django/area-test/app_usermanager_dev/devenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  62.     return template.render(context, request)

File "/home/max/Django/area-test/app_usermanager_dev/devenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  61.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/home/max/Django/area-test/app_usermanager_dev/devenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  171.                     return self._render(context)

File "/home/max/Django/area-test/app_usermanager_dev/devenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/home/max/Django/area-test/app_usermanager_dev/devenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/home/max/Django/area-test/app_usermanager_dev/devenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "/home/max/Django/area-test/app_usermanager_dev/devenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  150.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/home/max/Django/area-test/app_usermanager_dev/devenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/home/max/Django/area-test/app_usermanager_dev/devenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/home/max/Django/area-test/app_usermanager_dev/devenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "/home/max/Django/area-test/app_usermanager_dev/devenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  188.             return template.render(context)

File "/home/max/Django/area-test/app_usermanager_dev/devenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  173.                 return self._render(context)

File "/home/max/Django/area-test/app_usermanager_dev/devenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/home/max/Django/area-test/app_usermanager_dev/devenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/home/max/Django/area-test/app_usermanager_dev/devenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "/home/max/Django/area-test/app_usermanager_dev/devenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  443.             url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)

File "/home/max/Django/area-test/app_usermanager_dev/devenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/base.py" in reverse
  90.     return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))

File "/home/max/Django/area-test/app_usermanager_dev/devenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  673.         raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /account-manager/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'user_profile' with keyword arguments '{'username': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['account\\-manager\\/(?P<username>[^/]+)\\/profile\\/$']
```

Comment: It is `user_profile.profile_user.username` (with an underscore), not `userprofile.profile_user.username`

Comment: I see the same error with your indication. `userprofile` inside `userprofile.profile_user.username`  is a reference to the model `UserProfile`. I misunderstood?

Comment: no it is a reference to the context variable (in your `context {'user_profile': profile }`.

Comment: Ok, now now it's clear but, as I said, nothing is change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're incorrectly using the reverse `related_name` to get to the `user` when you have a `UserProfile` instance. Assuming you have a `UserProfile` instance in your context at `userprofile` your template should be:

`<a href="{% url 'user_profile' username=userprofile.user.username %}">User Profile</a>`

The `related_name` is for the *reverse* relationship, so if you had a `User` object called `user`, then `user.user_profile` will get you the related `UserProfile` instance, but when you have a `UserProfile`, the related `User` will be at `user`.

Comment: Nothing is changed. I've added the traceback at my question.